# Redirect output to /dev/null only if VERBOSE is not set

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, output-redirect

How would you accomplish this?

```sh
if [[ -z $VERBOSE ]]; then
    REDIRECT=">/dev/null 2>/dev/null"
fi

echo "Installing Pip packages"  # Edited in for clarity
pip install requirements.txt $REDIRECT

echo "Installing other dependency"
<Install command goes here> $REDIRECT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect all output using `exec`:

```
if [[ -z $VERBOSE ]]; then
    exec >/dev/null 2>&1
fi

pip install requirements.txt
```

If you want to restore the output later on in the script you can duplicate the file descriptors:

```
if [[ -z $VERBOSE ]]; then
    exec 3>&1
    exec 4>&2
    exec >/dev/null 2>&1
fi

# all the commands to redirect output for
pip install requirements.txt
# ...

# restore output
if [[ -z $VERBOSE ]]; then
    exec 1>&3
    exec 2>&4
fi
```

Another option is to open a file descriptor to either `/dev/null` or to duplicate descriptor `1`:

```
if [[ -z $VERBOSE ]]; then
    exec 3>/dev/null
else
    exec 3>&1
fi

echo "Installing Pip packages"
pip install requirements.txt >&3
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec` without a command:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ${VERBOSE:-0} -eq 0  ]]; then
   exec >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
fi

echo "Some text."
```

Example:

```sh
$ ./example.sh
$ VERBOSE=1 ./example.sh
Some text.
```

`${name:-word}` expands to `word` if the variable `name` is unset or set to an empty string. This way you can also have `VERBOSE=0` to turn it off.

Comment: Is there a way to turn that on and off on demand as a script asks as per my edit to my question?  Because this works, but it's not quite what I want to do.